# The difference between sequence-independent and sequence-order independent structural alignment?

Tags: sequence-alignment, structural-biology

I am confused about the difference between sequence-independent and sequence-order independent structural alignment. TM-align for example claims to be sequence-independent; however, I've seen it is also sequence order independent from the papers. To me, they sound like the same thing, but obviously, they aren't. Does anyone know about anything the difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.